# Does docker-compose have anything comparable to npm scripts, for executing container commands on demand?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker compose project with, among others, a "php-container". I often need to execute commands on that running container, for example `$ docker exec -it php-container ../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit tests/`.

Is there any way to do that with less typing? Ideally, I would define an alias in my `docker-compose.yml`, attach it to the php-container, and simply type `$ docker do testmystuff`. That would, in this example, run unit tests on the php-container, as if I had typed the full exec command from the first paragraph.

Something like this (simplified structure to get the point across--I realize there are design issues with this "schema").

```
# docker-compose.yml

# ...

services:
  php:
    container-name: php-container

# ...

usercommands:
  php-container:
    testmystuff: "../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit tests/"
    render-something: "./mycontainerscript render more-args-here"
    bash-php: "bash"
```

Answer (score 1):

Not that I'm aware of - though that could be cool.

How about a parameterized system alias or bash script in the meantime?

Something like

```
#!/bin/bash

CONTAINER=$1
TEST1=$2
TEST2=$3

docker exec ${CONTAINER} ${TEST1}
docker exec ${CONTAINER} ${TEST2}
```

Say this was `test.sh` then you could save a few keystrokes as

`bash test.sh php-container <TEST1> <TEST2>`

If your container and / or tests had stable names then this could become even more of a keystroke saver.

Your `test.sh` would express the entire exec command for a single test

```
#!/bin/bash

docker exec php-container ../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit tests/
```

and all you're left with is

`bash test.sh`

Comment: You may want `docker-compose exec php` instead

Comment: yeah - could be nicer to reference service instead of container name